# Stuck in importing file or project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.3

When I click on open project icon it keeps loading and doesn't show any thing..
[image]

I tried to remove .AndroidStudio2.3 and reopen android studio but it still does not work.

Comment: you reinstalled or just reopened ?

Comment: I just deleted android confg folder in my user profile

Comment: you may invalidate caches and restart.

Comment: Okay.I will try this